# What's a good way to compile client facing release notes for a git-flow managed software project?

Tags: git-flow, changelog

Very familiar with Git and git-flow (the paradigm and script to facilitate it), I recently took a shining toward git-extras changelog utility: it tags a landmark and updates a repo-tracked History.md file with raw commit messages since the previous changelog tagging.

What is the best way to administer and maintain this History.md using git-flow?  Right now I am issuing all the normal git-flow commands, but specifically just before a finish (of hotfix or release), I run:

```
git changelog --tag 2014_Nov13
```

for instance, vim History.md to manually strip out any "merged develop into master" and even prune and consolidated developers' commit messages into something more digestible for posterity, then issue

```
git commit -am "Updates History.md"
```

followed by git flow release / hotfix finish.

Is there a more appropriate way?